# Unable to interact with the Cross Validated in any way: "an error occurred, please try again"

Tags: bug, user-accounts, deleted-accounts, error-message

On the Cross Validated SE (and only on Cross Validated) I am unable to ask questions or answers. The error is simply "an error occurred, please try again". It has been going for a week now. I found other people that had the same problem, and I followed what they said "clear cached data". I did, nothing got solved. I even tried from another computer from home (different IP). No luck.

Growing desperate, I figured "I'll just delete my account on cross validated and try to rejoin the sub-community later. I'm new here anyway and only have 101 points".

But I am unable to delete my account. Exactly the same error : "an error occurred,  please try again".
EDIT 2: I was able to connect from a different browser and delete my account. I then rejoined the community but the problem did not go away. I should also specify that the tag suggestions (auto-complete) don't show up, nor does the list of possibly related questions (to avoid duplication) when I start writing the title of the question. The menus under the "recent achievement" and "recent inbox messages" do not work either, but the adjacent menus under "help" and "rest of stack echange sites" do work.

I have no other leads to explore... Any ideas ?

PS : I wanted to submit this question to Cross Validate Meta, but couldn't... "An error occurred submitting the question."

EDIT to answer Adam's comment:
When I open the firefox console, I find these errors, but they do not appear at the same time as when I click on upvote or other. They seem to have appeared before : (see screenshot

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe you are suspended on that site but nobody told you ...but you have the rep .. weird. You can visit your profile on CrossValidated and question pages, right? It just when you try to post anything, you're out of luck.

Comment: Yes, I do ! And I haven't really interacted with the site yet, I have 0 questions, 0 answers, 0 votes, I doubt that's the problem... I just have the 100 starting points "because they trust me on other sites". I can try to see if I can comment under a question or vote for a question

Comment: @rene suspension should result in a more meaningful error message, so that isn't the reason. This sounds more like an unhandled error during submission, which could be broken SE code, or broken client-side JS.

Comment: Just tried, can't vote, can't star, can't comment...

Comment: Try logging in with an entirely separate browser, where you haven't used SE before. That's probably the most reliable way to exclude that you have a corrupted version of the client-side SE Javascript.

Comment: @MadScientist yeah, there is known race condition during user profile creation that popsup now and then but still has no root cause. I suspect something similar here.

Comment: I am able to post a comment using another navigator I just downloaded. Should I try to remove my account there and adding it again ?

Comment: @ZakC I would just wait for a dev to arrive and investigate the issue.

Comment: @ZakC Are you able to star and upvote from this second browser?  If so, are you able to comment, star, upvote from your normal browser but in private or incognito mode?

Comment: @ZakC If you open up the browser console, do you see any errors in there when this happens?

Comment: @BrianNickel, no, I opened a "private session" window and tried. No luck. To Adam, no. If you mean "when I click on post, or star, or upvote, does something appear in the console at the same time as the red box appearing and saying "error", then no. but I do have others, I will edit the question to include them

Comment: I know this may sound rash, but you said you only had the starting bonus so what about deleting your account and then restarting. Have you tried this already?

Comment: @JakeSymons, that was exactly what the last idea I had when everything wasn't working, but even that made an error. If the problem isn't solved in a few days, I will delete my account using the other browser and try rejoin...

Comment: I edited the question, adding "I was able to connect from a different browser and delete my account. I then rejoined the community but the problem did not go away. I should also specify that the tag suggestions (auto-complete) don't show up, nor does the list of possibly related questions (to avoid duplication) when I start writing the title of the question. The menus under the "recent achievement" and "recent inbox messages" do not work either, but the adjacent menus under "help" and "rest of stack exchange sites" do work."