# I can't access Puzzling SE site

Tags: support

I can't access Puzzling SE site. Even I can't logging meta of Puzzling SE, because when I logging it comes to "`https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/login?ssrc=anon_ask&returnurl=https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask`" and same error appear....

That's why I asked question here instead of meta of Puzzling SE site.

[image]

Comment: No repro - I can visit Puzzling.SE without problems (although I was already logged in to SE when I tried). However, there has also been a report of [someone unable to visit Cross Validated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303479/168333). The problems _could_ be related.

Comment: @S.L.Barth However, now there is no problem and I did nothing...

Comment: I can visit [the site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/login?ssrc=anon_ask&returnurl=https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) without a problem. My browser Chrome 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)/

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson please provide us with your browser details so you can be helped furhter

Answer (score 3):

If you're *only* having this problem with puzzling.SE, and not with other SE sites, then it's almost certainly a problem at your end.

The reason I say this is because SE uses a [DNS wildcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) that points *any* host name of the form `*.stackexchange.com` to the same set of IP addresses.  You can try this by visiting a random made-up SE host name like, say, https://asdfghjkl.stackexchange.com: your browser will resolve the host name and load the page just fine, although the SE webservers will just give you a "no such site... yet" error page.

If there was something wrong with the wildcard DNS record, then it should affect *all* SE sites (except maybe those with their own domains, like SO).  If only one site fails to resolve, it's almost surely a problem with your own computer's DNS resolver.

---

As for what might be causing the error you describe, a common cause of intermitted DNS resolution errors is simply an unreliable Internet connection, e.g. due to a poor WiFi signal or a flaky modem.  DNS resolution is the first thing your browser does when you try to visit a new site, so if your Internet connection temporarily fails, often DNS will be the first thing to break.

(If your computer can detect that it's lost signal and gone offline, you may get a different error.  But if it *thinks* it's still online, but the packets are just getting dropped somewhere along the line, this is often the kind of error you'll get.)

Note that, typically, DNS errors caused by a flaky Internet connection should affect all sites, possibly at random if the connection comes and goes.  Of course, this may be hard to notice if you don't actively check for it by trying to visit other sites when one site fails.  Still, if it's *consistently* just certain sites that fail, while others still work, something else may be wrong.

One situation that I've observed causing such behavior is if your computer actually has *two* active Internet connections (e.g. a wired and a wireless connection), one of which stops working.  In that case, your computer may be trying to route packets to some sites over the failed connection and to others over the working one.  Admittedly, that's kind of an uncommon case, but it's one possibility to keep in mind.

It is, of course, also possible that a filtering firewall on your computer, or somewhere upstream, is blocking your connection.  However, usually such filters don't actually block DNS queries, but will either rewrite them to point to an internal IP address or just let the DNS query go through and intercept the connection at a higher level.  Either way, the result is that you'll typically get a custom error page instead of just a generic DNS resolution error.